# Not able to get correct traversal order with Jetpack compose in Android TV

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get correct traversal order when accessibility is enabled on Android TV.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen3() {
    val firstFocusItem = remember { FocusRequester() }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "This is a heading 3", modifier = Modifier.semantics {
            heading()
        })
        TvLazyRow(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(10.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.semantics {
                isTraversalGroup = true
                traversalIndex = 0f
            }
        ) {
            items(5) {
                if (it == 0) {
                    TextButton(
                        {},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .focusRequester(firstFocusItem)
                            .semantics {
                                isTraversalGroup = true
                                traversalIndex = 1f
                            }
                    ) {
                        Text("Item $it")
                    }
                } else {
                    TextButton(
                        {},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .semantics {
                                isTraversalGroup = true
                                traversalIndex = it.toFloat()
                            }
                    ) {
                        Text("Item $it")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        firstFocusItem.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

But its not working as expected. The order i'm looking is

Heading --> Down arrow --> First item of list --> Up arrow --> heading.

But the order i'm getting is

Heading --> Down arrow --> third item of list --> Up arrow --> heading.

How can i make it correct?